# Detatch Linq list from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Database where I can store Orders. I want to get all Orders where the Amount is bigger than 0 and then set the Amount in the Database to 0. The Problem is when I want to set the value in the Database also the value from the current selected orders get overwritten.

```
var order = db.Orders
              .Where(x => x.Amount > 0)
              .ToList();                //all Orders with an Amount > 0

 db.Orders
   .Where(x => x.Amount > 0)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => x.Amount = 0);        //after this line the Amount of the Orders in my List is 0
```

Is it possible to "detatch" the List from the database so I have the original amount in the list.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a feature :) But seriously, you can use *no tracking query* when retrieving the first list, e.g. `var order = db.Orders.AsNoTracking().Where(...).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @IvanStoev mentioned you can use `AsNoTracking()` to tell `entityframework` not to monitor your first query

```
var order = db.Orders
          .Where(x => x.Amount > 0)
          .AsNoTracking()
          .ToList();             

 db.Orders
   .Where(x => x.Amount > 0)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => x.Amount = 0);
```

Or you can use different instances of `DbContext` to do your queries.